# Landscape left preview for iPhone X in Interface Builder in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode9

In Xcode/Interface Builder we have convenient buttons to show our layout with different specific devices like iPhone X, iPhone 8 and so on, and also portrait and landscape. However the only landscape mode available is landscape right. Is there anyway to have IB show our layout in landscape left, so that the notch shows up to the right?